# multifile direct compile ok, direct compile error

Tags: c, makefile, segmentation-fault, coredump

There are 3 files(generator.c, generator.h and main.c).

generator.c: There is only 1 function (gen fun) which is used to generate an array to store 10 random-generate numbers in generator.c.

generator.h:Declaration of generator.c.

main.c: There is only 1 function (main fun) in main.c which is used to print the number generated previously.

If generator.c is included in main.c and I compile it directly by execute "gcc main.c". The result is ok.

But while I compile it using " *gcc -c generator.h, gcc -c main.c, gcc generator.o main.o* ", it reported a warning "**warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast**" at " *p = gen(arr)*; " sentence in main funciton. And the final result was "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". The debug information showed "**Cannot access memory at address**" if i try to visit the value of pointer *p(i.e. array[0])  in the while loop of main function.

```
//////generator.c///////
int *  gen( int arr[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int * p = arr;
    int len = 10;
    srand( (unsigned)((time)(NULL)));
    while (i< len)
    {
        *p = rand() % ( len  +1) + 0;
        i ++;
        p++;
    }
    return arr;
}

//////generator.h//////
int * gen( int arr[]);

//////main.c///////
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int arr[10]={0};
    int * p;
    p = gen(arr);

    while (i < 10)
    {
        printf("output is %d\n",*p);// Segmentation fault (core dumped)
        i++;
        p++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Second time I've seen `*p = rand() % ( len  +1) + 0;` -- Are you sure -- you don't mean `*p = rand() % len + 1;` ?? (to generate random between `1 <= *p <= 10`)? There is nothing else wrong with your code (that itself isn't wrong, just wonky)

Comment: *"But while I compile it using " gcc -c `generator.h`"* --- Do NOT include `generator.h` in your compile string....

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin   Actually, this is the second time I submit this question because the code previously contained some mistake...  I have seen the code example as " int num = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower". As for the code, I don't understand why there is no compile error but a final output error.

Comment: Yes, that is a *Range + Offset* for a range not beginning at zero. The difference between `rand() % (limit + 1)` (gives range of  `0 <= n <= limit`) and `rand() % limit + 1;` (gives range `1 <= n <= limit`) so it really just matters what you need.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin   Thank you for your prompt reply! The multi files compiling really confused me. The compiling process is pretty easy while get all functions in one file. But I am trying to practice how to write makefile to compile multi files of  C.  It is obvious that I am a newcomer in C language and If you can recommend some books for C learning , it will be very helpful to me.

Comment: [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) is a very good reference. The Questions & Answers here on StackOverflow about `make` are another very good reference.

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  Amongst many other problems:  it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files (this includes a `#include` for the `generator.h` in each of the *.c files.  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the actual problem and help you debug it

Comment: When writing a header file, like `generator.h` always include the include guard(s).  I.E.  at the top of `generator.h`:  `#ifndef GENERATOR_H newline #define GENERATOR_H`   Then at the end of `generator.h` the statement: `#endif // GENERATOR_H`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the addition to your question, it appears you are confused about how to include `generator.h` and then to compile the code. First your `generator.h` should be:

```
//////generator.h//////
#ifndef GENERATOR_H
#define GENERATOR_H  1

int *gen (int arr[]);

#endif
```

(**edit:** added appropriate *Header Guards* to prevent multiple inclusion of `generator.h`)

Your `generator.c` would then be:

```
//////generator.c///////
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "generator.h"

int *gen (int arr[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int * p = arr;
    int len = 10;

    while (i< len)
    {
        *p = rand() % len + 1;
        i ++;
        p++;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

And finally your `main.c` (I called it `gen.c`) would be:

```
//////main.c///////
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "generator.h"

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int arr[10]={0};
    int *p;

    srand( (unsigned)((time)(NULL)));

    p = gen(arr);

    while (i < 10)
    {
        printf ("output is %d\n",*p);
        i++;
        p++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Compile**

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 -Ofast generator.c -o bin/gen gen.c
```

(**note:** I would also encourage adding `-Wshadow` as a normal part of your compile string as well to identify any shadowed variables)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/gen
output is 8
output is 1
output is 5
output is 4
output is 9
output is 5
output is 4
output is 6
output is 5
output is 6
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: a good answer, except for a couple of details.  Specifically do not include header files in a header file unless the contents of that header file need them.  The file `generator.h` does NOT need  `#include <stdlib.h>` nor `#include <time.h>`  Also, The call to `srand()` should only be made once, typically at the top of the function: `main()`

Comment: Those are all good points. We  can move them into the sources that need them.

Comment: (the original answer being to show how to compile what the questioner had) The rearrangements while proper were not where they were stuck.